# How to put if else in ng-repeat statement

Tags: angular

```
     <div ng-repeat="d in data" ng-if="data.length>0">                                                    
         <div ng-bind="d.aa"></div>
         <div ng-bind="d.bb"></div>        
         <div ng-if="d.test == 'true'">
           <div ng-bind="it's test" />
           </div>    
         </div>
     </div>
```

Content:

1. I need to display d.test= true means , it's test like.
2. Normally ng-if is working fine, with in ng-repeat and ng-bind it does not work.

Please help this

Answer (score 4):

```
<div ng-repeat = "data in comments">
    <div ng-if="data.length >0">
        //different template with 0 data
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.type == 'story' ">
        //different template with story data
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.type == 'article' ">
        //different template with article data
    </div> 
</div>
```

you can use also

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results">
  <!-- If r.date contains a value, show it -->
  <span ng-if="r.date">{{r.date}}</span>
  <!-- If r.date does not contain a value show placeholder text -->
  <span ng-if="!r.date">Date not confirmed yet.<span>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, Thank you for the answers.

I need to if conditio in the between of ng-bind statement. Is it possible to put here? 
For binding data is it's need ng-bind?

Please help anyone. thanks.

<div ng-repeat="d in data" ng-if="data.length>0">                                                    
         <div ng-bind="d.aa"></div>
         <div ng-bind="d.bb"></div>
           <div ng-if="d.test == 'true'">
           
                     /*****  *// Here need code  for binding
           </div>    
         </div>
     </div>

Comment: Hello @Samy you can use ng-init  befhalf of ng-if.  i think it works for you.


<div ng-init="model = (title == 'Add Student' ? registration.Student : student.Student)">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50">
</div>